Let $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb {R}$ with $f^{'}_n$ uniformly bounded by $1$ and exists $f$ s.t $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Prove convergence is uniform.
Question:
Let $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb {R}$ with $f^{'}_n$ uniformly bounded by $1$. Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ s.t $f_n \to f$ pointwise in $[0,1]$. Prove convergence is uniform.

My attempt:
So for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$ I'm trying to bound the expression:
$$sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f(x)|$$
The first term is bounded by proving $f_n$ is 1-Lipschitz using MVT and the second term is bounded by the fact $f_n \to f$ pointwise. I'm not sure how to continue and would love direction or if maybe I'm all out in the wrong direction. Thank you!

Do you know Arzela-Ascoli Theorem?

@geetha290krm no it was taken off of our course this semester.

As you mentioned correctly, $f_n$ are all $1$-Lipschitz. By taking $n\to\infty$ we easily get that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz as well. So now let $\epsilon>0$. Partition the interval $[0,1]$ into parts $0=x_0<x_1<...<x_k=1$ such that $x_i-x_{i-1}<\epsilon$ for all $i$. For each $0\leq i\leq k$ there is some $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_i$.
Let $N\max\{n_0, n_1,...,n_k\}$. If $n\geq N$ and $x\in [0,1]$ then there exists some $i$ such that $|x-x_i|<\epsilon$. Then:
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq |f_n(x)-f_n(x_i)|+|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|+|f(x_i)-f(x)|\leq$
$\leq |x-x_i|+|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|+|x-x_i|<3\epsilon$
Where we of course used the fact that $f_n, f$ are all $1$-Lipschitz.

Thank you very much this is exactly what i was missing your proof is super neat and organized, thank you for taking the time!
